# for question about combinatorials

Tags: solution-verification

```
 on reading the following proof , I understand the reduction in the number of terms  by using the  "telescoping " method. My concern is terms such as the second term in:
```

$1\choose k+1$-$0\choose k+1$ which appears twice , is this a valid expression? as it =(1/((k+1)!.($0$-(k+1))!).Which in the second last term "looks " to be set to $0$

Working:

j+1 replacing n  and k+1 replacing k in.
${n\choose k}$=${n-1\choose k-1}$+${n-1\choose k}$ gives.
${j+1\choose k+1}$=${j\choose k}$+${j\choose k+1}$
so:

${j\choose k}$=${j+1\choose k+1}$-${j\choose k+1}$

$\sum_{j=0}^n{j\choose k}$=$\sum_{j=0}^{n} [{j+1\choose k+1}- {j\choose k+1}$]=[$1\choose k+1$-$0\choose k+1$]+[$2\choose k+1$-$1\choose k+1$]+....+[$n+1\choose k+1$-$n\choose k+1$]=$n+1\choose k+1$-$0\choose k+1$=$n+1\choose k+1$

thanks
        ralph.

Hello,
What I'm asking , is, $0\choose k+1$  what is the value of this expression , because in the second last term above it looks like the value is taken to be $0$

eg
$n+1\choose k+1$-$0\choose k+1$=$n+1\choose k+1$.But using the Combination formula 0! = 1 . So how is the expression arrived at ? thanks ralph

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I'm confused as to what you are asking :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is , the conventional formula for combinations:  $n\choose k$ does not apply here:

For k $ >= $ 1,n=0, there are no k-element subsets of [0] = ∅, so,$0\choose k$ = 0

ralph